# Play an mp3 file downloaded to filemanager using AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avplayer, nsfilemanager

I'm working on a project in `swift3` and I have a particular UIViewController to download an mp3 to my filemanager and using that path saved **I wants to play an mp3 using AVPlayer**. My code doesn't work, I think Im missing something. How would I achieve this?. My code to download the file to the filemanager as below

```
func downloadSong() {

    if let audioUrl = URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/feisty-beacon-159305.appspot.com/o/Aal%20Izz%20Well%20-%20Remix(MyMp3Song).mp3?generation=1490097740630162&alt=media") {

        // then lets create your document folder url
        let documentsDirectoryURL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!//since it sys first this may  only plays the first item

        // destination file url
        let destinationUrl = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(audioUrl.lastPathComponent)
        print("destinationUrl is :",destinationUrl)

        // to check if it exists before downloading it
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destinationUrl.path) {
            print("The file already exists at path")
             self.dest = destinationUrl.path
            // if the file doesn't exist
        } else {

            // you can use NSURLSession.sharedSession to download the data asynchronously
            URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: audioUrl, completionHandler: { (location, response, error) -> Void in
                guard let location = location, error == nil else { return }
                do {
                    // after downloading your file you need to move it to your destination url
                    try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationUrl)

                    print("file path is :",destinationUrl.path)
                    print("File moved to documents folder")
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }).resume()
        }
    }
}
```

And once I save that file, using its file path which is "destinationUrl.path" I initiate my player as bellow in a different UIViewController. As for now I have hardcoded the path I save. The code as bellow.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    //path I have saved in file manager is set to the url
    let url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath:"/Users/auxenta/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F3840294-04AA-46BE-9E46-4342452AFB69/data/Containers/Data/Application/670C0EA1-B375-498E-8847-8707D391D7BF/Documents/Aal Izz Well - Remix(MyMp3Song).mp3") as NSURL

        self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url as URL)
        self.player=AVPlayer(playerItem: self.playerItem!)
        let playerLayer=AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player!)
        playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 50) // actually this player layer is not visible
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    }

@IBAction func playBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
         if player?.rate == 0 // this means if its not playing
         {
            player!.play()
            print("playing")
            playbutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "pausebutton"), for: UIControlState.normal)

            //trackTime
            trackTime()
       } else {
            // getFileFromFieManager()
            print("pause")
            player!.pause()
            playbutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "playbutton"), for: UIControlState.normal)
      }

}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? download or, play?

Comment: my song doesnt play at all

Comment: The problem is this path `/Users/auxenta/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F3840294-04AA-46BE-9E46-4342452AFB69/data/Containers/Data/Application/670C0EA1-B375-498E-8847-8707D391D7BF/Documents/Aal Izz Well - Remix(MyMp3Song).mp3` rather than hardcoding the filepath recreate the file path by appending original filename, the way you are doing with FileManager while downloading, it will work.

Comment: U means the "destinationUrl.path" ?

Comment: Yes, because normally there are certain values in your hardcoded url that get changed, and your code can't find the mp3, there are two problems in your code 1. `lastComponentPath` instead use say `my.mp3` 2. Use the same filename while playing it should work.

Comment: would u be kind enough to put up the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the URL set to the AVPlayer. In fact hardcoding a path in iOS doesn't work, it can change at any time.

You need to use code it the same way as you destinationUrl:

```
    if let audioUrl = URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/feisty-beacon-159305.appspot.com/o/Aal%20Izz%20Well%20-%20Remix(MyMp3Song).mp3?generation=1490097740630162&alt=media") {
                
                
          let documentsDirectoryURL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!//since it sys first this may  only plays the first item
                
           // destination file url
           let destinationUrl = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(audioUrl.lastPathComponent)
           print("destinationUrl is :",destinationUrl)
            
           self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: destinationUrl)
           self.player=AVPlayer(playerItem: self.playerItem!)
           let playerLayer=AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player!)
  

                         .
                         .
                         .
}
```

Normally it should work. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use codes in the below. I hope I could helped you out. First you need to create path for the source file that you wanted to be play

```
 let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "yourFileName", ofType: "mp3")
        let soundUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

        do{

            try btnSound = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundUrl)
            btnSound.prepareToPlay()
        }
        catch let err as NSError{

        print(err.debugDescription)


        }
```

After you created these in the viewDidLoad method. You can create function for the playing sound like;

```
func playSound() {

       if btnSound.isPlaying {
         btnSound.stop()
        }

        btnSound.play()

    }
```

after all of these you can able to play mp3 files in swift.

Comment: file is saved to the filemanager in the phone locally and it has its own path, where it doesnt save the file name or the type. Thats why ive used" let url = NSURL.fileURL(withPath:"") " as my path which is "destinationUrl.path". From there i wants to extract the path and play

Comment: the question is NOT ABOUT AVAudioPlayer